# Distance between two 1D vectors that is non-euclidean.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have two vectors:

```
l1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
l2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

If I take the eucledian distance between l1 and l2, naturally the sum is 0. Now (from python and scipy distance package)

```
l1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
l2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
distance.eucledian(l1,l2)
>>> 1.4142135623730951
```

However, each of these positions represents and index in a sequence and I would like that to factor into the distance. For instance,

```
   l1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   l2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   l2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]



 distance(l1,l2) < distance(l1,l3).
```

Can anyone help me with the distance function? If math exchange is not appropriate for this question, may anyone suggest the proper forum?

Comment: I initially thought it would be a difference between the sums of indexes of each matrix...however, if one matrix is all 0.0, then it won't give the right answer and should be all eucledian

Comment: What do you mean by " I would like that to factor into the distance"? Do you mean want the distance along the curve? So $d(l_1,l_3) = d(l_1,l_2) + d(l_2, l_3)$?

Comment: The distance function. Indeed in this example, that would be true.

Answer (score 2):

The distance between two points $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n), b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n)$ is $$d(a, b) = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - b_k)^2}$$

To find the length of the piece-wise linear curve going from $l_1$ to $l_m$, sum the lengths of the segments:
$$\text{length }= \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} d(l_{k+1}, l_k)$$

There are no shortcuts to this, unless you have additional information about the points $l_k$.

Comment: I think you're missing the "2" in b_k^2.

Comment: @displayname - Actually, that formula was severely messed up. I'm not sure if I was asleep when I wrote it or what. The correct version is up now.